# Calling a second form's subform from the first form in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to call a second form's subform from a first form but I'm not sure if this is possible? my code is as followed:

```
            '2 get the corresponding section
        sectionInfo = GetSectionInfo(optPermit, arr)
            source = sectionInfo(0)
            heightNum = sectionInfo(1)
            topNum = sectionInfo(2)

            rootControl = "subfrmSection" + arr
            With Forms!frmSecondForm!rootControl.Form
                .SourceObject = "subfrmSection" + sectionInfo(0)
                .Top = currentLocation + sectionInfo(1) 'currentLocation + height of object
                .Left = leftNum
                .Height = cmdInfo(2)
                .Width = widthNum
            End With
```

I'm trying to edit the second form's subform on a button click but I keep getting the Error 2450 stating that it can't find this specific subform. Is there a different syntax for calling a subform in this situation?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: 
Thanks to the help of **pteranodon**, the final code now looks like this (for anyone who many need it):

```
'2 get the corresponding section
        sectionInfo = GetSectionInfo(optPermit, arr)
        rootControl = "subfrmSection" + arr
        Form_frmSecondForm.Controls(rootControl).SourceObject = "subfrmSection" + sectionInfo(0)
        Form_frmSecondForm.Controls(rootControl).Top = currentLocation + sectionInfo(1) 'currentLocation + height of object
        Form_frmSecondForm.Controls(rootControl).Left = leftNum
        Form_frmSecondForm.Controls(rootControl).Height = sectionInfo(1)
        Form_frmSecondForm.Controls(rootControl).Width = widthNum
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `!` notation is looking for a control literally named `rootControl`, not a control whose name is held inside the variable rootControl.

Try: `With Forms!frmSecondForm.Controls(rootControl).Form`

I can't tell if you have the same problem with `frmSecondForm`. If that is a variable and not the literal name, try:
`With Forms(frmSecondForm).Controls(rootControl).Form`

Comment: `frmSecondForm` is essentially the literal name in this case and not a variable. I tried your suggestion in wrapping `rootControl` in parenthesis and I still come up with the same error. This may be a silly question but I'm going to ask anyway: should `frmSecondForm` be `Form_frmSecondForm`?

Comment: Use exactly what is listed in the Navigator Pane when you press F11 and look in the Forms section. No extra characters. (I am presuming that the second form is already open when this code runs). If not, please specify.